python 3.14 - selenium cannot find button element
I'm trying to press the Follow button, on a reddit page via a click button.
I have opened the page in inspect mode, located the button and copied its XPATH into the code below. But the code is saying it cannot find the element.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

URL = "https://www.reddit.com/user/PBTech"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(5)
join_Btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.button-text")
join_Btn.click()
time.sleep(10)

join_Btn.click() throws an exception ... element not interactable
Please let me know the easiest way to click the subscribe button ... and if possible ... to display the entire HTML with driver.page_source or driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML") ... so that I may confirm the subscribe button has been clicked, replaced with an unsubscribe button, or changed to subscribed
Edit
Here is my full working example code ... including login sequance, because Shawn is saying the click is successful when it brings up the popup window.
I have included a basic GUI with 2 buttons,
Button1 - Click once you have logged in
Button2 - Run the code once you have confirmed the logging in (button 1)
You will also need an empty Globals.py file ... in the same folder
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import tkinter as tk
import Globals
import threading
import pdb
import os, sys





def logged_in():
    print("Login Confirmed!")
    print()
    Globals.logged_in = True
    time.sleep(1)
    Globals.logged_in1.config(text="Login Confirmed")
    Globals.run_auto1.config(text="Test Click Button")


def run_auto():
    if Globals.logged_in == True:
        wait = WebDriverWait(Globals.driver, 10)
        join_Btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.button-text")))
        join_Btn.click()
        time.sleep(10)
        Globals.all_Done = True
        root.destroy()

def start_GUI():
    URL = "https://www.reddit.com/user/PBTech"
    Globals.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    Globals.driver.maximize_window()
    Globals.driver.get(URL)

    while Globals.all_Done == False: time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("Exiting Web Browser...")
        time.sleep(3)

Globals.all_Done = False
Globals.all_Done = False
Globals.logged_in = False




root = tk.Tk()
# Creating a button with specified options
Globals.logged_in1 = tk.Button(root, text="Confirm Login", command=logged_in,activebackground="blue", activeforeground="white",anchor="center",bd=3,bg="lightgray",cursor="hand2",disabledforeground="gray",fg="black",font=("Arial", 12),height=2,highlightbackground="black",highlightcolor="green",highlightthickness=2,justify="center",overrelief="raised",padx=10,pady=5,width=15,wraplength=100)
Globals.logged_in1.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

Globals.run_auto1 = tk.Button(root, text="Run Test", command=run_auto,activebackground="blue", activeforeground="white",anchor="center",bd=3,bg="lightgray",cursor="hand2",disabledforeground="gray",fg="black",font=("Arial", 12),height=2,highlightbackground="black",highlightcolor="green",highlightthickness=2,justify="center",overrelief="raised",padx=10,pady=5,width=15,wraplength=100)
Globals.run_auto1.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

threading.Thread(name='process1', target=start_GUI).start()
root.mainloop()


Check the selenium browser if the element is there?

Are you sure you're logged in into your account, there is no cookies popup or something like that?

Check my answer for the issue related to your code. Regarding your second query, I am assuming you are referring to "Follow" button when you say "Subscribe"? If yes, once you click on Follow button, it opens a signup pop-up. You need to sign in first, then check if the button has changed from Follow to Following(Or something like that).

Yes! I will edit the post to say, "Follow"

What is the window size you have set for your browser?

I copied your exact code to my IDE and ran it. It is working fine for me. Code clicks Follow button and Sign up pop-up opens up.
Since you are getting Element not interactable exception. It is worth trying two things:

Open browser in full screen to ensure no other element is overlapping "Follow" button
Apply Selenium's Explicit Waits

Check the code below:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

URL = "https://www.reddit.com/user/PBTech"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(URL)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
join_Btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.button-text")))
join_Btn.click()
time.sleep(10)

Update: Try to click button using Javascript. See code below:
# join_Btn.click()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", join_Btn)


Hi Shawn, I also get the popup window if I run your code ... but when I login ... it throws the exception written above ... with your new addition of the wait function ... is throwing a new error ... selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException

I will post my full code above

Check the updated answer. See if that works.

Hi Shawn ... if I replace your wait.until ... with your old code ... join_Btn = Globals.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.button-text") ... and include it with your new suggestion ... Globals.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", join_Btn) ... then your code is now technically working ... But I cannot confirm because my dummy account is unable to complete the follow click ... even though it does press the button. This might be related to the account being new and following users not subs ... I will need to test this further to confirm its working.

I've tested this with my personal account ... and can confirm your new code works. With the old, join_Btn = Globals.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.button-text") (not the wait.until ... which still throws a timeout exception)

Glad it is working. What should I do when someone answers my question?
